# Proper way to display the result of large calculations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, double

When performing calculations on large numbers, how does one properly output the result in the right String format for the end user to see? I've tried the different format specifiers for NSString and compared the results to what the iOS Calculator app shows and some of the results aren't the same. Ideally it would match the iOS Calculator results exactly.

I know it needs to be displayed in decimal format until the number is sufficiently large, and at that point it needs to be shown in scientific notation. Therefore I thought `%g` was the right specifier. But it doesn't match the built-in calculator for the same calculation.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", calcResult] //where calcResult is a double`

Some examples:
123456.7 * 1 should display as 123456.7 but it is displayed as 123457 (puzzling!)
123456789 * 1 should display as 123456789 but it's displayed as 1.23457e+08
123456789 * 123456789 should display as 1.524158e+16 but it's displayed as 1.52416e+16

Also, how does one get the comma (or period depending on locale) to appear in the result? Are there additional specifiers one can use to get the exact format the iOS Calculator shows?

Comment: Use `NSNumberFormatter` to properly format the result based on the user's locale.

Comment: Check out this site, it helps: [type specifiers](http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/objective-c/types.html)
The first case for you might be caused because your calcResult isn't a double, or if you forgot to typecast somewhere (I understand you said it's a double, I'm just saying). The second example you provided is correct. %g is scientific notation for large numbers. If you do not want to display it as such, I would recommend using a different type specifier. The third result is simply a loss of data. If you want the correct result use an unsigned long instead of double.

Comment: There is no "Proper way to display" any number, it is to a large degree up to personal preferences and many calculator programs allow the user to make formatting choices. One person may be doing monetary calculations and want two decimal places, another scientific and want 5 decimal places. The calculator program probably does not use a stock display method. If you want a specific format you may need to write code to use different display methods for certain ranges of values.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, using `localizedStringFromNumber` with decimal style adds in the appropriate commas as necessary and takes care of example number 1. But now it's always displayed in decimal format (duh) - how would I combine that with scientific notation - @Zaph?

Comment: Use `+ (NSString *)localizedStringFromNumber:numberStyle:` and use `kCFNumberFormatterScientificStyle`.